# adding multiple class for form elements in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

How can I add multiple class to a form element using cakephp form helpers.
For eg: how to add a css class `col-sm-4` along with `form-control` in the below code.

```
echo $this->Form->select('subcat_id',$SubCategoryList, array('class'=>'form-control','id' =>'subcat_id','empty' => '-select subcategory-',
    ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just separates each class name by space.
like below.

```
   $this->Form->select('subcat_id',$SubCategoryList, array('class'=>'form-control col-sm-4'));
```